# white page in php can't find the error

Tags: php

Hey guys built an basic php script but  when i run it i have a white page can't find the error can someone else see it? The Table from where i collect Datas in mysql has the name `zurodnung` and i just want to read the datas out and output them as text.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
echo(<p>test1</p>);
include ("db_login.php");

    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Keine Verbindung zu der Datenbank moeglich.");
    mysql_select_db($db, $link);

    $sql = "SELECT ID_Zuordnung, HW_Typ, Hostname_alt, zuordnung.Username, Emailadresse, Datum_Ausgabe, Abteilung 
        FROM zuordnung
        WHERE Status_Tausch = 'OK' AND Status_Altgeraet = 'NOK'
        ORDER BY Hostname_alt;";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows ($result) > 0)  
    {
    $Farbe = "#fffffff";

            echo('<td bgcolor="'.$Farbe.'">'.$resultarray['HW_Typ']."</td>");
            echo('<td bgcolor="'.$Farbe.'">'.$resultarray['Hostname_alt']."</td>");
            echo('<td bgcolor="'.$Farbe.'">'.$resultarray['Username']."</td>");
            echo('<td bgcolor="'.$Farbe.'">'.$resultarray['Emailadresse']."</td>");
            echo('<td bgcolor="'.$Farbe.'">'.$resultarray['Abteilung']."</td>");
            echo('<td bgcolor="'.$Farbe.'">'.$resultarray['Datum_Ausgabe']."</td>");
    }
    else {
    echo(<h1>fail</h1>);
    }
    ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you turn on full error reporting and find out.

Comment: Where did you set the $resultarray value?

Comment: apart from the obvious error that is crashing your script - there are many things "wrong" here: do not use the mysql library (this is an ancient crusty library) - use either mysqli or, better yet, PDO; bgcolor is no longer valid HTML, and hasn't been for years; interspersing HTML and PHP like this is asking for trouble (leading to your problem finding the error) - put HTML into templates and pass information from PHP to the templates; learn how to set error reporting in PHP to help debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your echos are failing;

`echo(<p>test1</p>);` should be `echo('<p>test1</p>');`

and `echo(<h1>fail</h1>);` should be `echo('<h1>fail</h1>');`

FYI: echo doesn't require brackets, you could do `echo '<h1>fail</h1>';`

Comment: thanks works now i accept it when its possible

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably here: `echo(<h1>fail</h1>);` - you need to encapsulate that text in a string.

Now - before you do anything else - set up your development environment to give you the information you need:

1. Set error_reporting to E_ALL
2. Set display_errors to true
3. Find out where your error logs are (although, display_errors being on means that the browser will show messages, so you shouldn't have to monitor logs in a development environment - but this is useful for diagnosing production errors).

Answer (score 0):

Spaghetti code. Awful thing - try to avoid it.

Wrong lines in your code are:

```
echo(<p>test1</p>);
echo(<h1>fail</h1>);
```

should be

```
echo('<p>test1</p>');
echo('<h1>fail</h1>');
```

Also this code:

```
echo('<td bgcolor="'.$Farbe.'">'.$resultarray['HW_Typ']."</td>");
```

can be easily made more human readable this way:

```
printf('<td bgcolor="%s">%s</td>', $Farbe, $resultarray['HW_Typ'] );
```